# Is the way my GM is using smite correct?

Tags: spells, combat, advanced-fighting-fantasy

This is for the game Advanced Fighting Fantasy (2nd Edition).

From the book:

> Smite
>   This power allows the Priest to do greatly increased damage against the enemies of the God, specified for each deity. The power will last for a number of combat rounds equal to the Priest's Devotion and will allow the Priest to roll 2 separate D6’s for damage. The results of each damage roll are both applied to the target, and indeed any bonuses to the damage roll are applied to both rolls.

How it's currently used in my table:
"For a number of combat rounds equal to the Priest's Devotion, the priest can choose a target that is an enemy of their god, and then he can roll 2d6 damage against that target without having to try to hit"

What I can understand is:
"For a number of combat rounds equal to the Priest's Devotion, whenever the priest succeeds in hitting their target with their weapon, and if that target is an enemy of their god, then he can roll 2 instead of 1 dice for damage from his weapon's damage table".

If one of these interpretations is correct, which one is it? Otherwise, how does the spell work?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The way it works is that when the power is triggered, the Priest causes extra damage against enemies of his or her God.
Because damage is determined by a D6 roll on the specific weapon combat table, a normal hit will roll one D6, the STAMINA damage inflicted will be read from the table and that applied to the target.  Armour may reduce that damage.
With this power active, the priest can roll two separate D6's.  Both of these are read on the weapon combat table and both STAMINA damages added together before being reduced by armour and applied to the target.
If the priest has a power or spell that grants a +1 to their damage roll, this will apply to both D6's.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation and for the extra clarification on the behaviour of smite vs amor (I initially thought two separate armour rolls would be needed).